# how do i save progress for the user on Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

What is the method for a user saving progress without signing in or automatically signing in if the app is downloaded to a person's phone?

Many apps on the play store seem to have the progress saved directly to a person's phone. What method do I use to allow for my app's progress to be saved for each user?

Comment: What do you mean by progress? Do you refer to app keep track of activity user accomplished and resume on later?

Comment: I think you want something like async storage. It allow you store and retrieve data (strings) locally by key values.  https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/

Comment: For example, to retrieve data that is either stored on the phone or through an account on a database.

Comment: Async storage is temporary like local storage and so is not atall what I want.